# Problemas para configurar views usando django

Tags: python, django

Estou estudando django e estou com problemas na seguinte parte {'posts': posts} estou usando como ide pycharm e ele mostra erro mas para mim a sintaxe do código está correta.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post

def post_list(request): 
    Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date') 
   return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts' : posts})
```

Comment: Sua variável `posts` não existe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erro trivial:

```
def post_list(request): 
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date') 
   return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts' : posts})
```

Comment: Realmente obrigado, descuido meu nem percebi não havia atribuído posts.